# XSL Transformation Solution

Tags: xslt, transformation, altova, map-force

In my mapping project, I have a xsd based on this xml structure for source. Note the capitalized node names and attribute values:

```
<ROOT>
    <INPUT>     
        <NODEA
            ATT1="xxx"
            ATT2="xxx" />
        <NODEB
            ATT1="xxx" 
            ATT2="xxx" />
    </INPUT>
</ROOT>
```

And other xsd based on this xml for target. Note the lowercase names and element values:

```
<operation> 
    <input>
        <nodea>
            <att1>xxx</att1>
            <att2>xxx</att2>
        </nodea>
        <nodeb>
            <att1>xxx</att1>
            <att2>xxx</att2>
        </nodeb>
    </input>
</operation>
```

How can I get an XSL transformation, grouping by tree nodes, similar like this, with Altova MapForce 2017? Note the node comments and the name of variables:

```
<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <operation>         
        <input>                     
            <xsl:for-each select="INPUT">           
                <!-- NODEA -->
                <xsl:for-each select="NODEA">                   
                    <!-- ATT1 -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="@ATT1">
                        <xsl:variable name="v_ATT1" select="."/>
                        <att1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="string($v_ATT1)"/>
                        </att1>
                    </xsl:for-each>                 
                    <!-- ATT2 -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="@ATT2">
                        <xsl:variable name="v_ATT2" select="."/>
                        <att2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="string($v_ATT2)"/>
                        </att2>
                    </xsl:for-each>                 
                </xsl:for-each>             
                <!-- NODEB -->
                <xsl:for-each select="NODEB">
                    <!-- ATT1 -->
                    ...
                    <!-- ATT2 -->
                    ...
                </xsl:for-each>             
            </xsl:for-each>
        </input>
    </operation>        
</xsl:template>
```

The Altova MapForce creates this different solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_initial" select="."/>
        <operation xmlns="...">
            <xsl:attribute ...>
            <input>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='ROOT' and namespace-uri()='']">
                    <xsl:variable name="var2_cur" select="."/>
                    <att1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='INPUT' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='NODEA' and namespace-uri()='']/@ATT1"/>
                    </att1>
                    ...
                </xsl:for-each>
            </input>
        </operation>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is `<xsl:for-each select="NODEA"><xsl:for-each select="@ATT1">` good for? A certain element can only have a single attribute of a certain named (e.g. `ATT1`) so I don't understand at all what the inner `for-each` is good for. And your text says `grouping by tree nodes`, what does that mean? If an `INPUT` can have several e.g. `NODEA` children and you want to group them with XSLT 2.0 you should simply process `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name(.)">`.

Comment: The question is not clear. Are those two possible inputs to the same transformation? Or is one the input and the other the expected output?

Comment: I think you are right, there is no need to nest a for-each for attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to transform the first XML into the second one, then why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:param name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <operation> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </operation> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), $upper-case, $lower-case)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), $upper-case, $lower-case)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is no grouping involved here - just renaming nodes and converting attributes to elements.

Comment: Some times NODEA have other Camelcase names, for example FirstName, LastName... I have write a general case of name.