# Case insensive filter nodes from XML with XSL transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0. I have an XML document:

```xml
<profile>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>Email</name>
            <value>test@mail.com</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>joinDate</name>
            <value>1590438658</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>LAST_LOGIN</name>
            <value>1591638684</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>address</name>
            <value>1197 Franklin Street, Independence, Oregon 97351</value>
        </property>
        <!-- ... -->
    </properties>
</profile>
```

The property names have inconsistent cases, and they can change per document (e.g. `Email` might be `email` in another document). **I want to keep `property` nodes based on the case-insensitive value of the `name` tag.**

For instance, I want to keep `property` nodes with `name` equal to `email` or `address` (case-insensitive).

Expected output:

```xml
<profile>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>Email</name>
            <value>test@mail.com</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>address</name>
            <value>1197 Franklin Street, Independence, Oregon 97351</value>
        </property>
        <!-- ... -->
    </properties>
</profile>
```

I have tried this XSL transform, but it is not case-insensitive:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='property'][not(*[local-name()='name']
        [.='email' or .='address']
        )]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771718/xsl-transformation-solution/45772070#45772070

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thanks for the attempt. I was unsuccessful at adapting that answer to my problem. I posted my solution.

Comment: Actually, it seems you've got the principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='property'][not(*[local-name()='name']
        [translate(., $uppercase, $lowercase)='joindate' or
         translate(., $uppercase, $lowercase)='last_login'])]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If someone can show this more elegantly, then I will accept that answer.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, but (1) it doesn't compile (you cannot use variables in a match pattern) and (2) you did not say that the element **names** can vary in case. Translating only the **values** would make this much simpler.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, on point 2, I did not say that, but I am anticipating different element name cases since I cannot depend on consistent cases. I've removed that bit from the answer since it isn't relevant. On point 1, I'm no expert, but this is compiling for me and passing my tests. I see this _shouldn't_ work, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8839952/3133286). Still, it's working for me in my project using Spring WS.